# Superset UI: Refused to connect to 'https://example.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, apache-superset, talisman

This is CSP issue
i am trying to access the external api using fetch from superset React frontEnd.

To enable the csp
CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_WARNING = False

```
TALISMAN_ENABLED in config file
```

```
TALISMAN_ENABLED = utils.cast_to_boolean(os.environ.get("TALISMAN_ENABLED", 
False))
```

```
CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_WARNING = True

# Do you want Talisman enabled?
TALISMAN_ENABLED = utils.cast_to_boolean(os.environ.get("TALISMAN_ENABLED", True))

# If you want Talisman, how do you want it configured??
TALISMAN_CONFIG = {
    "content_security_policy": {
        "default-src": ["'self'"],
        "img-src": ["'self'", "data:"],
        "worker-src": ["'self'", "blob:"],
        "connect-src": [
            "'self'",
            "https://api.mapbox.com",
            "https://events.mapbox.com",
        ],
        "object-src": "'none'",
        "style-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        "script-src": ["'self'", "'strict-dynamic'"],
    },
    "content_security_policy_nonce_in": ["script-src"],
    "force_https": False,
}
# React requires `eval` to work correctly in dev mode
TALISMAN_DEV_CONFIG = {
    "content_security_policy": {
        "default-src": ["'self'"],
        "img-src": ["'self'", "data:"],
        "worker-src": ["'self'", "blob:"],
        "connect-src": [
            "'self'",
            "https://api.mapbox.com",
            "https://events.mapbox.com",
        ],
        "object-src": "'none'",
        "style-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        "script-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "'unsafe-eval'"],
    },
    "content_security_policy_nonce_in": ["script-src"],
    "force_https": False,
}`
```

i tried to enable it but it's not work for me